# Yarn no longer works on MacOS Catalina after yarn upgrade

Tags: yarnpkg

Running MacOs Catalina 10.15.7.

After receiving warnings about yarn being out of date I tried to upgrade it. I have tried several means and yarn no longer works on the machine.

After initially using yarn upgrade

I tried using the curl script: `curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -s -- --rc`

The install terminates with:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/xxx/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.1.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
> Yarn was installed, but doesn't seem to be working :(.
```

`which yarn` returns /Users/xxx/.yarn/bin/yarn

Wondering how to get past this and yarn working again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me when I tried yarn 2 & new workspaces

I got rid of it with `rm -rf /Users/xxx/.yarn`